# Склонение количественных числительных

Tags: лингвистика

Поправьте, пожалуйста:

- и. - один, одна, одно;
- р. - одного, одной, одного;
- д. - одному, одной, одному;
- в. - одного, одну, одно;
- т. - одним, одной, одним;
- п. - одном, одной, одном;

Особенно смущает аккузатив:

Винить кого, что?

- одного, двух, трёх, четырёх, пятерых [мужчин];
- одну, две, три, четыре [женщины] (или двух, трёх женщин);
- одно, два, три, четыре [события] (совпадает с имен.п.)

Answer (score 1):

Одну, две, три, четыре женщины. Ни в коем случае не двоих, троих женщин. Остальное правильно.

Comment: Я прошу прощениния, но "двоих", "троих" - это производное от "двое", "трое" (собирательные числительные), я же спрашивал о количественных числительных - "двух", "трёх". Относительно женского рода эти формы применяются в род.падеже как минимум.

Answer (score 0):

Услышала
 "кого?" -  двух женщин 
"что?"  - две отговорки 
Связано, скорее, с одушевленностью - неодушевленностью существительного

Answer (score 0):

так:
•*И. - один мужчина, стол; одна женщина, машина; одно дитя, яблоко; одни родители, ножницы;*
•*Р. - (нет кого) одного мужчины, стола; одной женщине, машины; одного дитяти, яблока; одних родителей, ножницы;*
•*Д. - (дать) одному мужчину, столу; одной женщине, машине; одному дитяти, яблоку; одним родителям, ножницам*
•*В. одуш. - (вижу) одного мужчину; одну женщину; одно дитя; одних родителей;*
•*В. неодуш - (вижу) один стол; одну машину; одно яблоко; одни ножницы;* 
•*Т. - (восхищаться) одним мужчиной, столом; одной женщиной, машиной; одним дитятей, яблоком; одними родителями, ножницами;*
•*П. - (о/об) одном мужчине, столе; одной женщине, машине; одном дитяти, яблоке; одниих родителях, ножницах;*

•*И. - два мужчины/двое мужчин, два стола; две женщины, машины; двух детей, яблок; двое родителей/два родителя, двое ножниц;*
•*Р. - (нет) двух/двоих мужчин, двух столов; двух женщин, машины; двух детей, яблок; двух/двоих родителей, двоих ножниц;*
•*Д. - (дать) двум/двоим мужчинам, столам; двум женщине, машинам; двум детям, яблокам; двум/двоим родителям, ножницам;*
•*В. одуш. - (вижу) двоих/двух мужчин; двух женщину; двух детей; двух/двоих родителей;*
•*В. неодуш - (вижу) два стола; две машины; два яблока; двое ножниц;* 
•*Т. (восхищаться) двумя/двоими мужчинами, двумя столами; двумя женщинами, машинами; двумя детями, яблоками; двумя/двоими родителями, двоими ножницами;* 
•*П. - (о/об) двух/двоих мужчинах, столах; двух женщинах, машинах; двух детях, яблоках, двоих/двух родителях, двоих ножницах;*

Простите за возможные опечатки, это был непростой труд.

Три и четыре - как два, с остальными числительнями обычно проблем не возникает.

Примечание 1. Одушевлённость слова дитя и производные формы для "двое ножниц" оспариаваются.

Примечание 2. Двое, трое и четверо - не только собирательное, это ещё и форма количественных числительных (в соответствующих случаях).